# How to convey the thanks directed at myself to others who have given a helping hand to do some work

Tags: communication, colleagues, work-environment, ethics, culture

I have arranged to deliver some goods to a covid infected person in our office after everyone in the department has contributed with money. That is, the goods were from the department's collected money. I only arranged to deliver them.

After I mentioned the successful arrangement in a WhatsApp group chat the others who contributed money said "Thank you Hasini". But I actually discussed with another girl, say "Jane" when arranging everything, so I think thanks should go to her too.

I actually mentioned her contribution to the head in a private WhatsApp message with the head, when the head thanked me there also. I said that "You're welcome. But I arranged everything together with Jane. I'll convey your thanks to her too".

But later, in the group chat again the head had thanked mentioning my name only, and others have followed. What should I do in this situation.

a) Should I say again that I did everything by discussing with Jane? Will it sound too much to say it again?

b)Should I stay silent and just say "You're welcome" or something like that?

c)Or should I say something like, "Thanks to you all too and specially Jane for discussing everything with me"

d) Or any other better and smooth way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Okay I'll post that type of comment to the group chat where they thanked me. Thanks a lot @JoeStrazzere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already mentioned Jane.

The best thing is just along the lines of 'Thanks, it was a team effort.'. This acknowledges the contributors as well as the delivery.

Comment: Yeah I felt like that too. Thanks a lot @Kilisi . I've replied saying "You're welcome and thanks to all of you too"